# React Native - Custom Alert with sound for noification received until user takes action on it

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, react-native, push-notification

Using package - `@react-native-firebase/messaging`

I want to achieve notification manager where user will receive continuous pings until he takes action on it even app is killed / background / foreground state.

Taking it further - Suppose 1 notification is received, I have not opened it, I will receive continuous pings with custom sound until I tap on notification to open it.

For it, From backend I am not sending default notification payload (as that automatically shows notification). So that I can handle by local notification defining my sound.

Here the example of code block to what I am referring -

```
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
    
    PushNotification.localNotification({
        ...
            id: '123'
        ...
    });
    
    setInterval(function () {
        playSampleSound({
          soundID: "277",
          url: "content://media/internal/audio/media/277",
          title: "FadeIn"
        })
    }, 2000); //run this thang every 2 seconds

});
```

Can custom modules described [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android) can help me in achieving the same?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are trying to annoy the user?

Comment: No @red_menace, Not annoying. Just force remind.